# RecyclerView inside DialogFragment inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to inflate RecyclerView inside the DialogFragment which is Inside a Fragment.
I made RecyclerView Adapter normally as per guidelines.

But I am getting this error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'voidandroid.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference`

On the line

> recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

Here's the complete code

```
public class AlertFragment extends DialogFragment {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter2;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;

ArrayList<String> goalname = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> goalcategory = new ArrayList<String>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alert, container, false);
    goalname.add("Running");
    goalcategory.add("Physical");
    goalname.add("Yoga");
    goalcategory.add("Physical");
    goalname.add("Gym");
    goalcategory.add("Physical");
    goalname.add("Meditation");
    goalcategory.add("Mental");
    goalname.add("Puzzle Solving");
    goalcategory.add("Habits");
    manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bookhistory);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);


    adapter2 = new GoalListAdapter(goalname, goalcategory,getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter2);
    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return v;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it is going to crash, because it's not finding recycler view instance.

**Just replace this line:**

```
  recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bookhistory);
```

**With:**

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookhistory);
```

Now it will work for you.

Comment: It worked but eventually app is still crashing because now adapter crashing

Comment: Post logcat for crashing of adapter

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                      at com.livelytoday.launch4.livelytoday.GoalListAdapter$RecyclerViewHolder.<init>(GoalListAdapter.java:63)

Comment: Problem is with your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with this line:

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bookhistory);
```

You really want to get the RecyclerView from the view that you inflated in your fragment on this line

```
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alert, container, false);
```

So to fix this, change the first line of code I mentioned to

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookhistory);
```

This is assuming that the DialogFragment contains bookhistory